# Options to improve container volume mount's SMB metadata operations performance

Tags: azure, server-message-block, containers, azure-app-services, azure-files

## Question

Are there any ways to improve metadata operation performance between a Linux based container running under Azure App Service and a mounted volume hosted in Azure Files?

## Context

I recently migrated a solution which had everything on one server to an Azure based solution where:

- The code runs on a container hosted under Azure App Service.
- Those files which are part of the business data are on Azure Files (i.e. a share under an Azure Storage Account) / mounted on the container (via the app service's `Settings` > `Configuration` > `Path Mappings` section).

This has introduced some performance issues with operations which search through a folder to see if certain files exist.  That's currently done via PHP's [file-exists function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

When testing on my local device, I can improve performance by appending `:cached` to the bind parameter; e.g. `--mount type=bind,source=d:\my\host\path,target=/var/my/container/path:cached`; but I can't find an option to do anything similar in Azure App Service.

My container's running Linux (`Ubuntu:21:10`); and I've read that SMB metadata operations (including checking if a file exists) have a higher overhead in Linux than Windows; so perhaps that's related (i.e. as Azure Files uses SMB); though I'm not certain (as the path is mounted to the container, so the container OS may not be aware of the underlying implementation).

I've enabled `large file shares` to increase the IOPs available to the file share; but it's made no difference (which given this is a metadata rather than IO performance issue, makes sense).

At present I'm thinking the solution would be to update the code to keep a representation of the file structure in the app's database so we can query that to get the same information faster; but this has the downside that every operation to upload or deleted a file needs to also update the database to keep disk and db info in sync / duplicates where information's held; so I'm keen to solve this infrastructure issue rather than recode if possible.

Comment: It looks like moving from SMB+AzureFiles to NFS+Container may be an option to improve performance: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support.  Sadly at present app service only supported read-only mounts for blobs...  https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/BringYourOwnStorage/mounting_azure_blob.md